# jQuery Mobile Listview Button not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I've hard coded in the HTML file directly the jQuery Mobile Buttons inside a Div and it shows up correctly. Please find the image below

[image]

But when I amend it via JavaScript those two buttons go missing. No idea why. Please find the image below

[image]

Can it be because of the jQuery Mobile Listview dynamically removes some styles something??

This is the HTML

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">    
<div id="ListOfCals">
<ul data-role="listview">
<li data-icon='false'>
<div id='ColorCodeDiv' style='background-color:#FFF;'></div>
Calendar 2
<p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#006600'>Active</font></strong></p>
<div id='calendarListView'>
<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='delete' data-theme='g' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='delete'></a>
<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='gear' data-theme='e' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='edit'></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript Code used

```
var strCalList = "<ul data-role='listview'>";
var ListOfCals = JSON.parse(data.d);
$(ListOfCals).each(function(){

strCalList +="<li data-icon='false'>";
strCalList += "<div id='ColorCodeDiv' style='background-color:"+$.trim(this.ColorCode)+"'></div>"
strCalList += this.CalendarName;
if(this.Active==true){
strCalList +="<p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#006600'>Active</font></strong></p>" ;
}
else if(this.Active==false){
strCalList +="<p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#FF0000'>Inactive</font></strong></p>";
}

strCalList +="<div id='dvBtn'>";
strCalList += "<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='gear' data-theme='e' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='edit' ></a>";
strCalList +="<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='delete' data-theme='g' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='delete'></a>";

strCalList +="</div>";
strCalList +="</li>";

});

strCalList = strCalList+"</ul>";
$('#ListOfCals').html(strCalList);
$('#ListOfCals ul').listview();
```

Can someone figure out why?? Thanks for the time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your example and for me it works without problems using Windows 7 and Firefox Nightly, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L83Gf/). Do you have the problem only with a specific configuration?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
      <div id="ListOfCals">
        <ul data-role="listview">
          <li data-icon='false'>
            <div id='ColorCodeDiv' style='background-color:#FFF;'></div>
            Calendar 2
            <p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#006600'>Active</font></strong></p>
            <div id='calendarListView'>
              <a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='delete' data-theme='g' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='delete'></a>
              <a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='gear' data-theme='e' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='edit'></a>
            </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </div>

     <script>
     $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
       var strCalList = "<ul data-role='listview'>";
       var ListOfCals = JSON.parse(data.d);
       $(ListOfCals).each(function(){

         strCalList +="<li data-icon='false'>";
         strCalList += "<div id='ColorCodeDiv' style='background-color:"+$.trim(this.ColorCode)+"'></div>"
         strCalList += this.CalendarName;
         if(this.Active==true){
         strCalList +="<p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#006600'>Active</font></strong></p>" ;
         }
         else if(this.Active==false){
           strCalList +="<p style='margin-top:2px'><strong><font size='2' color='#FF0000'>Inactive</font></strong></p>";
         }

         strCalList +="<div id='dvBtn'>";
         strCalList += "<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='gear' data-theme='e' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='edit' ></a>";
         strCalList +="<a name='del' data-role='button' href='#' data-icon='delete' data-theme='g' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-bttype='delete'></a>";

         strCalList +="</div>";
         strCalList +="</li>";
       });

       strCalList = strCalList+"</ul>";
       $('#ListOfCals').html(strCalList);
       $('#ListOfCals ul').listview();
     });
     </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```